# Wpml, как перевести атрибуты товара?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В плагине `wpml` можно ли переводить атрибуты товара?
Я нашёл только возможность переводить сами значения атрибутов, а именно название атрибута нельзя перевести с помощью данного плагина (т.е. по этому адресу `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes`), странно что нет такой возможности.
Подскажите, как ещё можно перевести атрибуты товара?

**P.S.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для перевода атрибутов WC вам нужно установить и активировать плагины:

- WPML String Translation
- WPML Translation Management
- WooCommerce Multilingual

Перевод атрибутов и их значений тогда станет доступен по адресу

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpml-wcml&tab=product-attributes
```

На странице `admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes` был создан атрибут

Его можно перевести здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дело в том что эти плагины уже установлены, и плагин `WooCommerce Multilingual` переводит только те атрибуты, которые добавлены уже непосредственно на странице отдельного товара, т.е. произвольные атрибуты, т.е. которые не зарегистрированы на этой странице `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpml-wcml&tab=product-attributes`. А те атрибуты, которые созданы на странице добавления атрибутов (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes`) эти атрибуты нет  возможности переводить, они не отображаются на странице перевода товара. Что можно придумать, подскажите?

Comment: Я не понимаю ващей проблемы. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: добавил в вопрос скриншоты проблемы. т.е. у товара есть три атрибута: `Наличие,Производитель, атрибут` (третий атрибут создан непосредственно на странице товара, т.е. его нет в выпадающем списке атрибутов), но на странице перевода для перевода доступны только `атрибут`

Comment: А выотключите все плагины WPML, и увидите, что при создании атрибута в товаре он не попадает в список атрибутов `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes` Проблема в WooCommerce

Comment: так какое решение?

Comment: Видимо, не создавать атрибуты в товаре - другого я не вижу.

Comment: кстати проблема была с существующими товарами, а если создавать новые товары, то атрибуты переводятся, хоть и некоторые атрибуты так и не отображаются на странице перевода товара